# How to clear screen of minicom terminal using serial UART

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, uart

I want to clear `minicom terminal` screen from UART connected to PC `/dev/ttyUSB0`. I know how to do it in PC by using shortcut `Ctrl + A then Z and select C` or `Ctrl + A then C`. Now I wanted to do the same by using UART. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I wanted to do the same by using UART.

The UART is employed to simply transfer data.  The UART has no access nor can it clear or control a **minicom** terminal screen/window.
Perhaps you are asking how the remote side of the serial connection can clear the screen, e.g. by sending a command sequence?

That answer would depend on which `terminal emulation` (e.g. ANSI or VT102) is configured for the **minicom** terminal, and if that terminal definition has a `erase screen` command string (aka *escape sequence*).
Turns out that the `erase screen` escape sequence is the same for both ANSI and VT102 terminals.

```
Esc[2J  Erase Display:
        Clears the screen and moves the cursor to the home position (line 0, column 0).
```

When the **minicom** terminal *receives* (from the remote side or when local echo is enabled) the 4-byte character sequence of `Esc[2J`, this escape sequence is intercepted, not displayed, and then the terminal window will be cleared.

The four characters are:

```
 Esc     the ASCII Escape character, value 0x1B.  
 [       the ASCII left square brace character, value 0x5B.  
 2       the ASCII character for numeral 2, value 0x32.  
 J       the ASCII character for the letter J, value 0x4A.
```

---

References
[ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)
[ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm).

Answer (score 3):

@sawdust - clear/concise answer, thanks!
I had the same issue, your answer resolved it. Since I was already using `printf` for my PIC to send text and data over to a host terminal, it was easy to add:

```
printf("%c%c%c%c",0x1B,0x5B,0x32,0x4A);
```

When the terminal screen got messy with data.

Answer (score 0):

From [TTRM Supported Control Functions](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/4/en/about/ctrlseq.html#CSI), Escape Sequence 'c' can be used to reset the terminal.

```
printf("%cc",0x1b);
```

If intention is to only clear current display, and not the entire buffer:

```
printf("%c[2J", 0x1b);
```

Followed by this, if you want to move the cursor back to row:column 0:0, then:

```
printf("%c[0;0H", 0x1b);
```